# Set focus through attribute at run-time

Tags: javascript

I am setting focus on specific HTML element at run-time through JS as given below:

```
var el = document.getElementById("input-control");
el.focus();
```

However I want to do this by using attributes. I tried `autofocus` attribute but it only works when page loads. Is there any attribute available which I can set at run-time which would set focus in input element.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that's your only option.

Comment: You can assign a data attribute like `data-autofocus` on any element and look for such an element in JS with `document.querySelector('[data-autofocus]')`. Is that what you had in mind or are you looking for a solution that doesn't require any Javascript?

Comment: Do you want to focus an element without JS? What do you mean by Run-time.